# How to get the chu bombs bag in Legend of Zelda: Phantom hourglass?

Tags: zelda-phantom-hourglass

I am currently in the Goron island and I think I need to use those chu bombs(available at the Goron store) to unlock something in the maze to get to the Goron island temple. I need to have a chu bom bag though to use those bombs. Where can I get that bag for chu bomb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [zeldawiki.org](http://zeldawiki.org/Bombchu_Bag), you can obtain it by either finding it in a treasure chest at the Goron Island Dungeon or completing the Cannon Minigame at Dee Ess Island in 35 seconds or less.
There's also a store selling it at the Goron Island Store for 1000 rupees.

Comment: You're referring to the chu bomb bag right? there's no chu bomb bag available in the goron island store, just the chu bombs. I can't go to zeldawiki.org btw.

Comment: The Bombchu Bag at the store is available only after you obtain it at the Goron Temple

Comment: I guess you're missing something. You have no need to use bombchus to access the Goron Temple since you obtain the Bombchu bag once you're INSIDE the temple.

Comment: Aww okay. Thanks for answering. I'll figure out the maze part without those chu bombs I guess. Or if you know how to open  that switch at the end of the maze that seems only accessible by a chu bomb, tell me please :)

Comment: There's a switch on the maze that can be pressed only by a Bombchu (altough I can't remember what it triggers), but it is not used to open the way to the Goron Temple's entrance. At the end of the maze you'll see some spikes in front of the stairs leading to the temple's entrance. In order to clear the spikes you just need to kill the monster that's in front of it.